# Buscar variáveis de sessão joomla para php

Tags: php, session, joomla

Um cliente tem um site feito em joomla, e tenho que integrar o login que ele faz no seu site para o meu site em php. Mas não sei como ir buscar as variáveis de sessão do joomla. Como as posso ir buscar? Ou como posso ver o nome delas?

Comment: $session = JFactory::getSession(); echo $session->get('name'); já tentou isso ?

Comment: tentei agora mas não faz nada

Comment: podes ver como ele armazena na session e criar uma classe ou uma function para acesso a session. Para ver como ele armazena faça: \var_dump($_SESSION);die();

Answer (score 2):

Dentro de um arquivo PHP do joomla, já inicializado e preferencialmente logado (se você trabalhar com login no joomla), coloque o seguinte código:

```
<pre>
<?PHP print_r($_SESSION); ?>
</pre>
```

Dessa forma você verá todas as variáveis de sessão inicializadas até aquele momento.  Para usar, basta acessar:

```
<?PHP echo $_SESSION["nome_da_variavel_mostrada"]; ?>
```

Lembrando que isso precisa ser posto no site em JOOMLA.  Para você passar essas variáveis de sessão do site dele para o seu, seria interessante se tudo estivesse no mesmo servidor e domínio, para o navegador manter a mesma identificação de sessão.

Answer (score 2):

Com esse código você vai ter as informações da sessão do Joomla

```
<?php
// Recuperando Sessão do usuário Joomla
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
$path = "\\xampp\htdocs\seuprojeto";  //caminho da instalação do Joomla
define('JPATH_BASE', $path);
require_once JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php';

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();
$mainframe->initialise();
$user =& JFactory::getUser( );


echo $user->id;  //imprime id do usuário
echo $user->name; //imprime nome do usuário
echo $user->password; // Imprime senha do usuário
```

Answer (score 0):

Para você dar um dump na Session atual do Joomla basta fazer o seguinte código:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
var_dump($session);
```

E a partir deste objeto, poderá adquirir as informações que deseja.